# Is spartacus 4.3.1 compatible with SAP commerce 2205?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have a quick query regarding Spartacus. Please let me know if Spartacus version 4.3.1 is compatible with SAP commerce version 2205?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

the latest Spartacus 4.x was tested with 2205. The parts that are new in 2205 (for example, new future stock api feature) are not yet supported, but that doesn't stop you from using 2205 itself. Support for most of new features is planned for rest of 2022.